# CSRF not working in django with safari private browsing

Tags: django, cookies, safari, private, django-csrf

I am unable to POST data to my django webapp in safari private browsing (it works with Chrome incognito).

I am not using localstorage.

I set the X-CSRFToken header using

```
var csrftoken = NMA.getCookie('csrftoken');
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    beforeSend: function (request, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain){
            request.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    },
    url: "/profiler/logAnswers/
    data: payload,
    dataType: 'json'
}).done(...
```

The csrftoken cookie is set using {% csrf_token %} and the hidden input is present inside the `<form>`

I have inspected the request using charles and the csrftoken cookie is set and the X-CSRFToken header is set.

I have noticed that safari in private browsing adds "DNT = 1" (do not track) to the header, not sure if this is causing the problem. The DNT=1 is not present in chrome incognito requests.

I have logged the cookies in

> python2.7/site-packages/django/middleware/csrf.py

using

```
logger.debug(request.COOKIES)
```

and the csrftoken cookie is missing (and several other cookies are missing). There are only 4 cookies printed. There are 13 cookies present in the initial request as seen in charles.

As there is no csrftoken this causes the

> Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.) 403 error.

What does the DNT=1 in the header do? Does it limit the number of cookies allowed? Does it prevent certain types of cookies?

Comment: take a look http://osxdaily.com/2012/08/21/how-to-enable-do-not-track-in-safari-6/

Comment: I dont want to enable or disable it.  I want my webapp to work if the user is using private mode in safari. The DNT header seems to change how django handles the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that (in order to get around localstorage not being available) I have json objects saved in cookies.  There is a python bug or issue:

> https://bugs.python.org/issue27674

that causes only some of the cookies to be decoded if there are any quotation marks in the string.

So solution is to replace the quotation marks in all of the cookies